# Http listener for Message broker

Tags: httplistener, messagebroker

What is the function of biphttplisetner in message broker?
is it just for the HTTP nodes?(HTTPInput,HTTPReply etc) or is it required for some other functionality of message broker.

I am seeing that biphttplistener is not coming up if the database connection url specified in tnsnames.ora is not proper. What is the connection between this httplistener and database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have very little info around the case (versions, logs etc), but in a nut shell: biphttplistener is the http listener that feeds SOAP input and HTTP input nodes. Typically, it's setup to listen to the broker servers public network interface on a given port, such as 7080.

As for relation to db, please provide versions and logs to help trouble shooting

Comment: thank you Petter. I checked logs and found a table not found exception(e.g., BROKERAAEG etc). It was because the database where the new url was pointing did not contain default tables that were created when message broker was craeted. I am not sure which exact table was required for the biphttplistener.